# How to call globally dictionary stored in a variable in C# Console?

Tags: c#, dictionary, console-application

I have a variable called `users` it stores my defined dictionary and I want to call globally call `users` to access all its values however when I try to use `public static var users` I get an error saying it only applies locally.

`var users` is located in  `Login.cs` and I want to pass it to `Menu.cs`.

> Login.cs

```
namespace Bank
{
    public class Login
    {
        public static void LoginMenu()
        {
            var users = new Dictionary<int, User>()
            {
                {1, new User {UserName="sachin",Password="sachin1",FirstName="Sachin",LastName="Karnik",BirthDate= new DateTime(2011,6,14),Balance=20000,CardNumber=012345}},
                {2, new User {UserName="dina",Password="dina1",FirstName="Dina",LastName="Meyers",BirthDate= new DateTime(2012,8,20),Balance=20000,CardNumber=023456}},
                {3, new User {UserName="andy",Password="andy1",FirstName="Andy",LastName="Rose",BirthDate= new DateTime(2010,2,11),Balance=20000,CardNumber=034567}},
            };   
         }     
     }
}
```

> Menu.cs

```
namespace Bank
{
    public class Menu
    {
        public static void BankMenu()
        {
          foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(1,3)){
            Console.Write(users[i].FirstName +"\n");
          }
        }
        
     }
     
}
```

Comment: You declare the variable inside a function. It won't be available outside said function. Move the declaration to class scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fredrik wrote, you have declare the variable inside the function so it won't be available outside of this function. Move the declaration to class scope.
You should also notice that *var* keywork may only appear within a local variable declaration.

You should write it as following:

 **Login.cs:**

```
namespace Bank
{
    public class Login
    {
        public static Dictionary<int, User> users;
        public static void LoginMenu()
        {
            users = new Dictionary<int, User>(){
                {1, new User {UserName="sachin",Password="sachin1",FirstName="Sachin",LastName="Karnik",BirthDate= new DateTime(2011,6,14),Balance=20000,CardNumber=012345}},
                {2, new User {UserName="dina",Password="dina1",FirstName="Dina",LastName="Meyers",BirthDate= new DateTime(2012,8,20),Balance=20000,CardNumber=023456}},
                {3, new User {UserName="andy",Password="andy1",FirstName="Andy",LastName="Rose",BirthDate= new DateTime(2010,2,11),Balance=20000,CardNumber=034567}},
            };
        }     
   }
}
```

**Menu.cs**

```
namespace Bank
{
    public class Menu
    {
        public static void BankMenu()
        {
          foreach(var i in Enumerate.Range(1,3)){
            Console.Write(Login.users[i].FirstName +"\n");
          }
        }
        
     }
     
}
```